# How to change the margin widths in the MDT class?

Tags: margins, thesis, fullwidth, fullpage

I am typing using this class, https://www.latextemplates.com/template/masters-doctoral-thesis

It seems to me that using the ``\fullpage" on top of this causes the text to go crashing into the "headsepline" at the top of the page.

Is there a way to get the effect of fullpage (in particular its use of the full width of the page) without using \fullpage? Anyway to change the margin widths in this MDT class to simulate fullpage?

---

The preamble of the file does invoke the geometry package and it has the following settings by default,

```
\geometry{
    paper=a4paper, % Change to letterpaper for US letter
    inner=1.5in, % Inner margin
    outer=1in, % Outer margin
    bindingoffset=.5cm, % Binding offset
    top=1.5cm, % Top margin
    bottom=1.5cm, % Bottom margin
    %showframe, % Uncomment to show how the type block is set on the page
}
```

If I switch off ``\fullpage" and do some adjustment to this (what?)  can I recover the usage of the full width of the paper?

Comment: You are asking this question for the third time now. It is still unclear to me though, where your troubles are. You haven't received any answers yet, because other people here seem to be just as confused as i am.

Comment: By the way, i wouldn't recommend to use this class at all.

Comment: What is unclear about this question? I want the text to use the full width of the page while using the MDT class while not loading the fullpage package. How do I achieve this?

Comment: Set the inner and outer margins to some value that pleases you.

Comment: Is there any news here?